# My if statement behaving abnormally in my program Why it is returning false for true condition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

```
console.log(listName);      //Today
console.log(listName == 'Today'); //false---------it should be true
console.log('Today' == 'Today'); //true
```

Comment: Please add a [MRE]

Comment: Perhaps `listName` has whitespaces in it. But with the provided code, we can only guess...

Comment: You need to show the code that sets `listName` as this should work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/4xsLujvp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hunch is that, `listName` might have some whitespace characters? If `==` doesn't work, but it should work, I am definitely sure `===` will not work. So try trimming the value:

```js
listName = "Today ";
listName = listName.trim();

console.log(listName);
console.log(listName == 'Today');

listName = "Today";
listName = listName.trim();

console.log(listName);
console.log(listName == 'Today');

console.log("Trying ===");

listName = "Today ";
listName = listName.trim();

console.log(listName);
console.log(listName === 'Today');

listName = "Today";
listName = listName.trim();

console.log(listName);
console.log(listName === 'Today');
```

With the above being said, I have added a copy with `===` too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..

Comment: actually i was reading route parameter dynamicly in listName but browser was secretly sending request to favicon.ico tha's why i am getting the error and i have already tried the trim(). thanks again

Comment: Ohhh @SachinSingh I guessed it!

Comment: @SachinSingh Add more details about how you get the `listName`, so that we can reopen the question. Since you're a first timer, it's fine. 